# Cypher path that doesn't cross certain nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to cypher but struggling with what seems like a basic query.

I need to get the paths between all nodes marked with property IsPrimaryEntity (PE)
without the path including any other PE nodes

```
(PE1)----(n1)------(n2)-(PE2)-(n3)-(PE3)-(PE4)
     \(n4)-(n5)---/
```

would produce just 4 results

```
(PE1)-(n1)-(n2)-(PE2)
(PE1)-(n4)-(n5)-(n2)-(PE2)
(PE2)-(n3)-(PE3)
(PE3)-(PE4)
```

Here's what I currently have

```
MATCH p=(s {IsPrimaryEntity: true})<-[*..10]->(o {IsPrimaryEntity: true})
WHERE NOT s=o
RETURN p,s,o
```

It's important not to return a path (PE1).....(PE4)  ?

thanks,
Shaun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you were able to track this with an additional label, like :PrimaryEntity.

We can use [APOC Procedures path expander procs](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths) for this, as it's tricky to do this with Cypher alone.

Here's the query I used to create your sample graph:

```
create (PE1:PrimaryEntity {name:'PE1'})-[:REL]->(:Node {id:'n1'})-[:REL]->(n2:Node {id:'n2'})-[:REL]->(PE2:PrimaryEntity {name:'PE2'})
create (PE1)-[:REL]->(:Node {id:'n4'})-[:REL]->(:Node {id:'n5'})-[:REL]->(n2)
create (PE2)-[:REL]->(:Node {id:'n3'})-[:REL]->(PE3:PrimaryEntity {name:'PE3'})
create (PE3)-[:REL]->(PE4:PrimaryEntity {name:'PE4'})
```

We can use `apoc.path.expandConfig()` for your query, as we want all possible paths, but we want to ensure we stop when we reach another :PrimaryEntity node (we'll use the termination label filter, which will let us expand only to :PrimaryEntity nodes and then stop expansion. The only paths returned will be to these nodes). We'll also use a predicate on the ids of the start and end nodes to ensure we don't return paths that are circuits back to our start nodes, and that we don't return mirrored paths (same path, but with the start and end nodes switched).

```
MATCH (p:PrimaryEntity)
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(p, {labelFilter:'/PrimaryEntity', maxLevel:10}) YIELD path
WHERE id(p) < id(last(nodes(path)))
RETURN [node in nodes(path) | coalesce(node.name, node.id)] as paths
```

The return is only to produce easily readable output.

This gets us:

`╒════════════════════════════╕
│"paths"                     │
╞════════════════════════════╡
│["PE1","n1","n2","PE2"]     │
├────────────────────────────┤
│["PE1","n4","n5","n2","PE2"]│
├────────────────────────────┤
│["PE2","n3","PE3"]          │
├────────────────────────────┤
│["PE3","PE4"]               │
└────────────────────────────┘`